# how to classify a list of lists by elements length?

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I have a list of lists, looks like this :

`List=[[1,3],[3,4,7,9],[4,7],[2,4,5,3],[5,7,4]]`

I want to classify the list elements according to their length, so the result looks like this:

```
2ElelmentSublist=[[1,3],[4,7]]
4ElementSublist=[[3,4,7,9],[2,4,5,3]]
....
```

And so on.

I read a post about `itertools.groupby()`,
But I couldn’t figure out how to apply it in my case.
Any pythonic way to do so?

Note: no need to have the result in separate variables,I need a way to know how many types of lengths I  have, and a way to reach every group separately.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make lists with dynamic names to be decided at run-time (like your `2ElementSublist` or so.)

But you can design a dictionary with keys as length, and values as lists of lists.

Try this:

```py
result = {}
for L in List:
    result.setdefault(len(L), list()).append(L)
print(result)
```

and you will see

```
{2: [[1, 3], [4, 7]], 4: [[3, 4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 3]], 3: [[5, 7, 4]]}
```

`.setdefault(k, d)` either gives you access to the dictionary value of key `k`, or initialize with a default value `d`. And you append each list.

Comment: this code worked for me perfect . but today I discovered that some lists returned distorted(their elements order change ) when I sample form them , I want to know if the problem from the code:

Comment: sorry my comment not completed : I mean the lists element orders get distorted : for example : Lengths=list(result.keys()), LeftLists=result(lengths[0])#( this is to get items of first length), leftListsSample=random.sample(LeftLists).  Now I get some lists out of order , for example a list like l=[1,3,4,5] , in the sample it ll be like [4,3,5,1].

Comment: I think you should post a new question for that.

Comment: Thank you , I discovered the problem, I sorted lengths using list.sort() instead sorted(list) which leads to mutating the original lists . Python sometimes so confusing .

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` by `len`:

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [[1,3],[3,4,7,9],[4,7],[2,4,5,3],[5,7,4]]
print( [list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=len), key=len)] )
#or
print( {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=len), key=len)} )
```

**Output:**

```
[[[1, 3], [4, 7]], [[5, 7, 4]], [[3, 4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 3]]]
{2: [[1, 3], [4, 7]], 3: [[5, 7, 4]], 4: [[3, 4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 3]]}
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, This is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most pythonic, but you can call values similar to how you wanted.

```
x = [[1,3],[3,4,7,9],[4,7],[2,4,5,3],[5,7,4]]
dic = {f"{len(i)}_elelment": [] for i in x}

for i in x:
    dic[f"{len(i)}_elelment"].append(i)


# {'2_elelment': [[1, 3], [4, 7]], 
#  '4_elelment': [[3, 4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 3]], 
#  '3_elelment': [[5, 7, 4]]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned you need the list grouped by `len` and need them in seperate variable I think you will be needing a `dict` as your final output.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from collections import defaultdict

List=[[1,3],[3,4,7,9],[4,7],[2,4,5,3],[5,7,4]]

res = defaultdict(list)
for _, v in groupby(sorted(List, key=len)):
    l = list(chain(*v))
    res[len(l)].append(l)

# Output : defaultdict(list,
            {2: [[1, 3], [4, 7]],
             3: [[5, 7, 4]],
             4: [[3, 4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 3]]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
List = [[1,3],[3,4,7,9],[4,7],[2,4,5,3],[5,7,4]]

sizes = set([(len(element)) for element in List])
result = {}
for element in List:
    if len(element) not in result.keys():
        result[len(element)] = []
    result[len(element)].append(element)
print(result)
```

And `result` is:

```
{2: [[1, 3], [4, 7]], 4: [[3, 4, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 3]], 3: [[5, 7, 4]]}
```

Comment: Thank you, your time and effort is appreciated.